# Android Studio 2.2.1 - Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit

Tags: android-studio

I am new here so I would like to apologise if I do/say anything wrong firstly. I have Googled this issue and searched Stack Overflow for it as well but it was not the *exact* problem which I am having.

I am currently doing `Rob Percivals Android N Developer course on Udemy.com` . In the course they recommend that you work in Android Studio 2.2.1 (which they generously provide a download link for).

I installed this on my machine and immediately I encountered a JDK/JRE issue which I solved through a quick Google. Then when it came time for me to create a new project, a whole new problem appeared.

Here is what I am doing (I'm sure if you're reading this you are 100% familar with Anroid Studio and don't need screenshots hence why I didn't provide any):

1. Create new project
2. I am choosing "Phone and Tablet Only" with and API 15
3. I am checking on "Generate new layout file" and "Backwards Compatibilty"
4. Finish

Now immediately. an error message pops-up `"Grade 'xxxxx' project refresh failed. Unable to start the daemon ... object heap"`

The solution proposed on Stack Overflow was to go into the "gradle.properties" file and change "-Xmx1536m" to "-Xmx1024m" and then close and open Android Studio. While this works, my question is do I have to do this every time I start a new project? Is there no permanent fix here?

I have read through all other suggestions such as deleting the .gradle folder in my Users folder and File Menu - > Invalidate Caches/ Restart->Invalidate and Restart but none of them works for me.

I would appreciate any responses.

Comment: It's not a question anymore, it's a biography..Anyway this : `"-Xmx1536m" to "-Xmx1024m` is a permanent configuration. No need to remake each time but to be on you could just as easily open your settings and watch if nothing has changed ...

Comment: Each time I start a new project from scratch, the code always reads "-Xmx1536m" which I have to manually change each time to "-Xmx1024m".

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 :

Steps to solve problem in android studio

1. Click on file and select a other setting from dropdown menu and then select default setting.
2. Select build,Execution,Deployment option.
3. Select Compiler
4. Here add a following line in Additional build process VM option

   ```
   -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=524m
   ```

[Check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPVIZ.png)

Answer 2 :

```
Try deleting your .gradle from C:\Users\<username> directory and try again
```